# Как сохранить свои функции в PHP

Tags: php

Кто знает способ сохранить функции в PHP? Т.е. не определять их, а чтобы они были  изначально, при запуске php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите модуль, подключите его к PHP и пользуйтесь при запуске изначально.

Или скачайте исходники PHP, добавьте нужные функции, скомпилируйте и пользуйтесь на здоровье

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться директивой *auto_prepend_file*, поместив её в `php.ini`

```
auto_prepend_file="/путь/к/файлу.php"
```

указанный в директиве файл [будет автоматически обрабатываться перед основным файлом. файл вызывается так, будто он был подключен при помощи функции require](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

вот в этот файл (`/путь/к/файлу.php`) можно и поместить свои *всегда доступные* функции.

Comment: это дикий антипаттерн, автору на самом деле нужен растолковать про библиотеку, а саму конфигурационную опцию *во избежание* выключить и никогда не включать.

Comment: а что плохого может сделать конфигурационная опция, чего не смог бы сделать сам php?

Comment: Все то, что может сделать автоинжект кода.